# Why WebJars are not extracted into a lib folder

Tags: playframework, webjars, scala-template

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/AssetsOverview#WebJars),`webjars` are automatically extracted by `Play` into a `lib` folder relative to the our public assets, but after installing `bootstrap` from `webjars`, I still have no lib folder. No lib folder under `/public`, no lib folder under `/target`.

I am having this compilation error:

```
not found: value lib
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at(lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css)">
```

I am certainly doing something wrong.

This is my `routes` file:

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

This is my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "contact-manager"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "3.3.1"
)

enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing qoutes around `lib/bootstrap/...`, since `Assets.at()` takes a string as argument. In your code `lib` is a variable and thus comes the message `not found: value lib`.

Comment: So in fact the `webjars` are not extracted in my public folder, they are just linked somehow to the `/assets/` url, right ? because I don't see them.

Comment: No, `webjars` are not extracted to the folder `<root>/public` but to `<root>/target/web/node-modules/` and `<root>/target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/`